# Strange icon with "N" letter in Note 5 phonebook

Tags: stock-android, samsung-galaxy-note

When I try to add new phone number to an existing contact, some kind of icon appears in phone number field. Please see screenshot:

[image: ss]

Thus happens since upgrading to Android 6.0.1.  What is that?